# Alexa skills kit, trouble getting session attributes to persist

Tags: session, alexa-skills-kit

I have been working on a skill where I am using Login With Amazon account linking so I can grab the user email address and name to use in my skill.  I am doing something similar to the scoreKeeper sample, using the eventHandlers.js and the storage.js for saving items to a database.  In the eventHandlers.onLaunch I am successfully getting the profile name and email address from Amazon and I save it to the session.attributes like this:

```
      var profile = JSON.parse(body);
                speechOutput="Hello, " + profile.name.split(" ")[0] + ".";
                var sessionAttributes = {};
                sessionAttributes = { name: profile.name, email: profile.email };
                session.attributes = sessionAttributes;
                console.log("Name in session:", session.attributes.name);
```

The console log shows the name so I know it is being saved in the session.attributes, but when I try to access the session.attributes in my storage.js or intentHandlers.js, it shows it as being empty.  What am I missing?  Thanks in advance.  This has been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working by adding session to the callback of the response.ask function, like this:

```
   ask: function (speechOutput, repromptSpeech, _session) {
        this._context.succeed(buildSpeechletResponse({
            session: _session,
            output: speechOutput,
            reprompt: repromptSpeech,
            shouldEndSession: false
        }));
    },
```

It had session: this._session for saving the session, but that didn't seem to be working for me.  Passing it as a variable did.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to obtain city name from the user and be able to access that value later in the Alexa session:

1) Pre-define your key/value pairs in the JSON response:

```
def build_response(session_attributes, speechlet_response):
return {
    'version': '1.0',
    'sessionAttributes': {
        "session_attributes": {
            'NameOfCity': city_name,
        }
},
    'response': speechlet_response
}
```

2) In global scope, declare the variable as an empty string:

```
city_name = "",
```

3) Whenever you update that variable within a function, make sure you reference that variable as global. For example:

```
def set_city_name_in_session(intent, session):

card_title = intent['name']
session_attributes = {}
should_end_session = False

if 'CityIntent' in intent['slots']:
    global city_name
    city_name = intent['slots']['CityIntent']['value']
```

4) When creating a function that needs to access this variable, pass the global variable as an argument into the function then, within the function, expose all session key/pair values like so:

```
def access_variables(intent, session, city_name):

card_title = intent['name']
session_attributes = {}
should_end_session = False
exposed_attributes = session['attributes']['session_attributes']
city_name_attribute_value = exposed_attributes.get('NameOfCity')

if (some_kind_of_condition):
    do something awesome with city_name_attribute_value
```

To test, enter sample utterances into Service Simulator then check if values are persisting in your Lambda JSON response.

Comment: heads up you don't wanna declare your variables on a global scope, the container you use might not get the same container on subsequent lambda calls...