# Alexa Skills - How does sessionAttributes actually work?

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I've been trying to get my head around this for days, it is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41755696/alexa-skills-kit-trouble-getting-session-attributes-to-persist) but that answer didn't solve my problem.

I can't populate the sessionAttributes property of the JSON response from my Alexa skill:

```
var sessionAttributes = {};
sessionAttributes = { "somekey": "somevalue" };
session.attributes = sessionAttributes;
```

I thought the response sent from my AWS Lambda function that responds to requests from Alexa would then include my custom addition, but this is not the case and I can't figure out why.

I think I understand that the response object is private to the closure accessed by this.response, but that only confuses me more (Source: [Github Issue](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/issues/89))

So my question is: **How can I persist data throughout a session involving multiple user interactions with Alexa?**

I am thinking it is required to build my own response object, I can't use any of the automation functions?

Comment: `I thought the response sent from my Lambda function would then include my custom addition but this is not the case, and I can't figure out why.` which lambda function?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to code-dump - I am using AWS Lambda to host the code that forms this Alexa Skill, I'll clarify that in my post as I know Lamda functions and AWS Lambda are entirely different!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a call to [setSessionAttributes](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/f167aa0f-8abe-4602-b985-65118b3032ca/code-deep-dive-slots-and-session-attributes-in-the-ask-sdk-for-node-js) which makes the new value of sessionAttributes available to other handlers.

So what you'd need to do is:

```
var sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
sessionAttributes.somekey = "somevalue";
handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(sessionAttributes);
```

Note: the above sample requires that you're using the Node SDK 2+ version.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for this, don't know how I missed that.